# Can multiple files be specified when using BFG?

Tags: git, version-control, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am trying to delete multiple types of files which cannot be covered by a wildcard. I tried using multiple --delete-files but it won't accept it. Also tried putting the files all after one --delete-files and it doesn't accept it either.

Is there a way to put them all in one command? If not, then do I have to run git `reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` after deleting each type of file with bfg or can I just run bfg multiple times and then run that command after?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out that you can use a blob surrounded in quotes like `"{a*,b*conf}"` for example.

Comment: Thank you and yes indeed this worked 100% for me `java -jar bfg-1.12.15.jar --delete-files "{continue.txt,result.txt,list,hosts,*active.txt,percentage.txt,inactive.txt,invalid.txt,*.zip}" my-repo.git/`

Comment: awkward. if you want to add a file to an existing list like "*.{model,xmodel}" then you need to expand it to "{*.model,*.xmodel,newfilename}"

Comment: For those using this: do NOT put a space after each comma.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something like this a while back and created a [pull request](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner/pull/137).