# How to free `*.jpg` files from latest status git?

Tags: git

As some `*.jpg` files already tracked by git,then `git lfs track '*.jpg'` cannot track those files.
How to make those `*.jpg` free from git HEAD(latest status)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As detailed in "[Moving a file in your repository to Git Large File Storage](https://help.github.com/articles/moving-a-file-in-your-repository-to-git-large-file-storage/)"

> If you've set up Git LFS, and you have an existing file in your repository that needs to be tracked in Git LFS, you need to first remove it from your repository.
>
> 1. Remove the file from the repository's Git history using either the `filter-branch` command or BFG Repo-Cleaner.
>      For detailed information on using these, see "R[emoving sensitive data from a repository.](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository)"
> 2. Configure tracking for your file and push it to Git LFS. For more information on this procedure, see "[Configuring Git Large File Storage.](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-git-large-file-storage)"

- you can remove files based on [wildcard with `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42939453/6309), or with [BFG repo cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879127/6309).
- you can [track multiple files in one command with lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46334726/6309)

Comment: I have read this post,but it's for single file.This question refer to `*.jpg`.

Comment: Finally, I give up `git lfs`,too many risks,waste my several days.

Comment: @kittygirl I was commuting to work. I have now edited the answer.